# jQuery form validation not working in CakePHP 2.8.5

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Actually my HTML form contains textboxes with name like, for example `name="data[User][username]"` in CakePHP 2.8.5.

How can I write jQuery form validation code for this form fields. Why because when I use validation I have to use the textbox field name, I cannot use the entire textbox name as `data[User][username]`.

My code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.min.css'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min'); ?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
        $("#UserAddForm").validate({ 
            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {
                username: "required",
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },            
                full_name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                phone: "required",
                role: "required"            
            },        
            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {
                username: "Please enter the Username",
                full_name: "Please enter your Full Name",
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"     
            }, 
        });
    });
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form" name="add_userform" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="UserAddForm" action="/invl_exams/users/add">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  required="required" id="UserUsername" maxlength="255" name="data[User][username]" >
                <!--<p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p> --> 
                <label id="UserUsername-error" class="error" for="UserUsername"></label>    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password:</label>                                    
                <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserPassword" name="data[User][password]">
                <label id="UserPassword-error" class="error" for="UserPassword"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserFullName" maxlength="255" name="data[User][full_name]">
                <label id="UserFullName-error" class="error" for="UserFullName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserEmail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][email]">
                <label id="UserEmail-error" class="error" for="UserEmail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Secondary Email</label>                             
                <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecEmail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][secondary_email]">
                <label id="UserSecEmail-error" class="error" for="UserSecEmail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone</label>                             
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][phone]">
                <label id="UserPhone-error" class="error" for="UserPhone"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Secondary Phone</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][secondary_phone]">
                <label id="UserSecPhone-error" class="error" for="UserSecPhone"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Location</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecLoc" maxlength="255" name="data[User][location]">
                <label id="UserLocation-error" class="error" for="UserLocation"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Business Name</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserBusinessName" maxlength="255" name="data[User][business_name]">
                <label id="UserBusiness-error" class="error" for="UserBusinessName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="UserDocument">Document</label>     
                <select class="form-control" required="required" id="UserDoc" name="data[User][document]">
                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                    <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
                    <option value="License Certificate">License Certificate</option> 
                    <option value="Aggrement Copy">Aggrement Copy</option>
                </select>
                <label id="ExamName-error" class="error" for="UserDocument"> </label>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="form-group">
                <label>File input</label>
                <input type="file">
            </div> -->
            <div class="form-group" id="ShowDoc" style="display:none">
                <label>File</label> 
                <!--<input name="data[Document][docfile]" id="DocumentSubmittedfile" type="file"> -->
                <!--<input type="file" name="data[User][docfile]" id="usersFile"/>-->
                <?php //echo $this->Form->input('doc_file',array( 'type' => 'file','error' => false,'placeholder'=>'Upload Image')); ?> 
                <?php echo $this->Form->file('Document.submittedfile');  ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h4 class="page-header">Point of Contact</h4> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>   
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pname" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pname]">
                <label id="UserPName-error" class="error" for="UserPName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>                                      
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pemail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pemail]">
                <label id="UserPEmail-error" class="error" for="UserPEmail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pOfc_phone]">
                <label id="UserpPhone-error" class="error" for="UserPEmail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <label>Designation</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pDesign" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pdesignation]"> 
                <label id="UserpPhone-error" class="error" for="UserpDesign"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">NEXT</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add quotes to your name  `rules: {"data[User][username]"  :"required"`

Comment: I used like this as below

Comment: I used like this   $("#UserAddForm").validate({        
        rules: {
            "data[User][username]": "required"},       
        messages: {
            "data[User][username]": "Please enter the Username",            
            },            
            
        }, 
    });

Comment: in the console or on the page?

Comment: In console validate is not a function error but in page there is no error

Comment: @RagithThomas then that means that the validate library isn't properly added to your page

Comment: I have already include the jquery.js file and jquery.validate.min.js file in the head section.Only in cakephp it's not working but in seperate html test file it's working fine

Comment: you didn't include them properly

Answer (score 0):

You can add desired ID to a field using CakePHP Helper just by passing additional parameter id while creating and use that id to bind validation.

PHP

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('company_name', array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'type' => 'text','id'=>'companyname','class' => 'form-control','autocomplete'=>'off','required'));  ?>
```

JS

```
$("#companyname").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength:2,
        maxlength:50, 
        messages: {
            required:"Please enter Company Name",
        }
    });
```